# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > After adding google play services

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**Update:**
I made the changes suggested by Nitesh but still receive the same error. I updated my code below to show how my build.gradle files look now

I get this error on trying to build and run my app after I added `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'` to my dependencies.

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have read a lot of posts with people getting the same error but nothing suggested has worked for me. If I remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'` from my build.gradle everything works fine though. Obviously that is not an option though

So far I have tried:

1. Clean/Rebuild Project
2. Added `multiDexEnabled true` to defaultConfig
3. added `dexOptions{incremental true javaMaxHeapSize "4g"`
4. Made sure there were no duplicate libraries

Here is my full app level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.codebyjordan.ancientcityapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'se.akerfeldt:okhttp-signpost:1.1.0'
    compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my project level gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: have you set android studio to use jdk 8?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in your **project** level `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Also add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the end of **app** level `build.gradle` file. And build again.

put this line in the end of app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I tried them but still receive the same error. I have updated my question to show the changes I made to my code.